# Facebook Graph api fetching fb posts to display in a website using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I want to fetch all posts from a public facebook page to display them in a website using javascript.

I did the code below based on docs but not sure why it doesn't work! The docs doesn't provide clear instructions or examples.

Any idea how to fetch facebook posts using javascript?

```
 const getPosts = async () => {
window.FB.api(
  "[pageID]/posts",
  "GET",
  {
    access_token: [token]
  },
  async function (response) {
    
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

};

Comment: what means "it does not work"? did you debug it? why the async function? the FB API does not provide promises (unless they changed that in last months). also, what token are you using, and did you apply for page public content access?

Comment: It gives me an empty array. Do I need to add anything before pageID? I'm confused because it's not a url format '[pageID]/posts'. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "me" or a real Page ID - and make sure to use a Page Token of that page:

```
window.FB.api(
    "me/posts",
    "GET",
    {
        access_token: page_token_of_that_page
    },
    (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```